# Checked static cast on a reference

Tags: c++, templates, casting

Long ago I have created a following template so that I get an assert whenever I perform a static_cast but the type is not what I assume it to be:

```
/// perform a static_cast asserted by a dynamic_cast
template <class Type, class SourceType>
Type static_cast_checked(SourceType item)
{
  Assert(!item || dynamic_cast<Type>(item));
  return static_cast<Type>(item);
}
```

Today I wanted to create a variant which would work not only with pointers, but with references as well:

```
/// overload for reference
template <class Type, class SourceType>
Type &static_cast_checked(SourceType &item)
{
  Assert(dynamic_cast<Type *>(&item));
  return static_cast<Type>(item);
}
```

However, the compiler does not seem to use this overload when I am casting a reference to another reference. I am afraid I do not understand template resolution rules enough to understand why, or to be able to create a variant which works.

*Note: I cannot catch the `bad_cast exception` instead of checking `dynamic_cast<Type *>` for NULL, as exceptions are disabled for this project.*

Comment: Can you add an overload for `SourceType*` and retire the original one?  Do you need to support value types at all? (And does that fix the problem, I am now wondering?)

Comment: I thought about these lines of code, and I can not understand why it is needed. If you check a static cast with a dynamic cast, than only objects can be checked static casted with are dynamic castable. That meens it is a reimlementation of `dynamic_cast`. The difference between dynamic and static cast ist, that the dynamic cast investigates the vtable and the static one not.

Comment: It is a static cast, but one which asserts - i.e. notify you debug time your assumption about the type you are casting is wrong.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Remove `*` and `&` from the return types:

```
/// perform a static_cast asserted by a dynamic_cast 
template <class Type, class SourceType> 
Type static_cast_checked(SourceType *item) 
{ 
  Assert(!item || dynamic_cast<Type>(item)); 
  return static_cast<Type>(item); 
} 

template <class Type> struct make_pointer
{
    typedef Type *PointerType;
};

template <class Type> struct make_pointer<Type &>
{
    typedef Type *PointerType;
};

/// overload for reference 
template <class Type, class SourceType> 
Type static_cast_checked(SourceType &item) 
{ 
  Assert(dynamic_cast<typename make_pointer<Type>::PointerType>(&item)); 
  return static_cast<Type>(item); 
}
```

Then you can use your desired syntax:

```
Derived *d= static_cast_checked<Derived *>(b);
Derived &d= static_cast_checked<Derived &>(b);
```

EDIT: added a pointer type conversion.

Comment: You can not get the pointertype out of a reference (`Assert(dynamic_cast<Type *>(&item));`) at least if you are using the gcc - I'm not sure about other compiler.

Answer (score 2):

This works:

```
/// perform a static_cast asserted by a dynamic_cast
template <class Type, class SourceType>
Type* static_cast_checked(SourceType *item)
{
  Assert(!item || dynamic_cast<Type*>(item));
  return static_cast<Type*>(item);
}

/// overload for reference
template <class Type, class SourceType>
Type &static_cast_checked(SourceType &item)
{
  Assert(dynamic_cast<Type *>(&item));
  return static_cast<Type&>(item);
}
```

Use it like this:

```
Dervied d;
Base* pbase = static_cast_checked<Base>(&d);
Base& rbase = static_cast_checked<Base>(d);
```

This solution relies on overloading function templates. Your solution didn't work because your first template is too general, it already includes your second function. Note that there is no specialization for function templates! You can only specialize class templates.

Comment: Great, this is easy and it works quite well. If possible, I would prefer a solution which would still allow me to write static_cast_checked<Base *> or static_cast_checked<Base &>. Can anyone create some? I am now trying to use a specialized template class to do the hard work, which sounds promissing.

Comment: I tried various attempts (including type traits and class specializations) and did not come to a compiling solution.

Comment: I think I have found a solution, with a combination of overloads and class specializations. Can you please check my new answer, to see if is OK?

Answer (score 1):

```
#include <boost/type_traits/add_pointer.hpp>

template <class Type, class SourceType>
Type static_cast_checked(SourceType *item)
{
  assert(!item || dynamic_cast<Type>(item));
  return static_cast<Type>(item);
}

template <typename Type,  class SourceType>
Type static_cast_checked(SourceType &item)
{
   typedef typename boost::add_pointer<Type>::type TypePtr;
   assert(dynamic_cast< TypePtr >(&item));
   return static_cast<Type>(item);
}
```

This implementation works like `static_cast` or `dynamic_cast` from the std-lib:``

```
    Base &b    = static_cast_checked<Base&>( a);
    Base* bPtr = static_cast_checked<Base*>(&a);
```

Comment: Nice. It does almost the same as my solution and the technical background is the same, but using boost it can be a bit shorter.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
template<class Type, class SourceType>
Type* static_cast_checked(SourceType* item)
{
    // ... 
}

template<class Type, class SourceType>
Type& static_cast_checked(SourceType& item)
{
    // ... 
}
```

Then every pointer would use the first variant and every reference will use the second at the rules of partial specialization (IIRC).